# Odd reuse in the evaluation of these expressions

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use Debug.Trace.trace to figure out how many times a function is evaluated, and seeing some surprising results.

```
ghci> import Debug.Trace

ghci> let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) 3 in (x, x)
( Eval'd!
6, Eval'd!
6)

ghci> let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) 3 in x `seq` (x, x)
Eval'd!
( Eval'd!
6, Eval'd!
6)

ghci> let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) (3 :: Int) in (x, x)
( Eval'd!
6,6)
```

I'm making the assumption that `Eval'd` is printed once for each evaluation of the `(* 2)` function. Is that a correct assumption?

Secondly, why is the function ever printed more than once? I suspect that `x` being of some unspecified type of the `Num` typeclass has to do with it given that the third case works but I can't think of an explanation.

`(x, x) :: Num a => (a, a)` guarantees that the two elements of the tuples have the same value just as much as `(x, x) :: (Int, Int)`, so why eval `x` twice?

UPDATE:

Actually I had assumed that the type of `(x, x)` was `Num a => (a, a)`. But it's apparently `(x, x) :: (Num t, Num t1) => (t, t1)`.

Why does GHC not realize that `t ~ t1` here? I suspect it's related to the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're *not* guaranteed to be the same type:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> :t let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) 3 in (x, x)
let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) 3 in (x, x)
  :: (Num t, Num t1) => (t, t1)
```

Also, if you put it in a file, it only gets evaluated once, even when called from GHCi. (This is because in declarations in files but not GHCi, the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5) is on by default):

```
import Debug.Trace
main = print $ let x = (trace " Eval'd!" (* 2)) 3 in (x, x)
```

Also,

```
let x = (trace " Eval'd!" 6) in (x,x)
```

behaves about the same, so it's really all in the type (class) ambiguity.

The reason why it doesn't share all uses of `x` is because at GHC core level `x`, unoptimized, is really a *function* taking a `Num` typeclass dictionary argument. To share it, it has to do enough analysis to see that the types are the same.

The reason why it doesn't realize is basically that GHCi is intended for fast code experimentation turnaround, not for creating good code, so it does nearly no optimization at *all*, so it's almost pure luck whether it detects such things or not.

(There's also an [outstanding hole](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1257) in the GHCi bytecode design that means you *cannot* enable optimization levels for it, even if you'd want to. Basically it doesn't support "unboxed tuples", which GHC optimization uses a lot.)

Comment: I think I see what you mean `let x = 3` => (x, x) :: (Int, Integer) => no type error. So `x` and `x` aren't necessarily the same type once displayed since a different `Num` dictionary could be passed.
Interesting.

Comment: @obadz, to confuse matters further, enabling certain type system extensions turns off let generalization, forcing the two to have the same type (unless you give a type signature). I don't know if that will change anything for GHCi though.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh duh, that's why putting it in a file changes it, I should explain that.

Comment: @dfeuer The other restriction you're probably thinking of, [`MonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#mono-local-binds), doesn't change anything in this case because `x` is "closed". Here's a version where it matters: ``let f y = let x = (y `seq` trace " Eval'd!" 6) in (x, x) in f 0``